# How to use the JavaScript loop index in the ViewBag list string

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I want to use the JavaScript index to get the value of the viewBag list.
But I have a mistake in combining the two.
Thanks for guiding me

```
<script>
    for (var i = 0; i < @(Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.paramProperty)); i++) {
        select: `@(ViewBag.paramProperty[ + "${i}" + ]);
        var element = document.querySelectorAll(`[value="${select}"]`);
        element[0].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: select: `@(ViewBag.paramProperty[ + "${i}" + ])`;  ==> select: `@(ViewBag.paramProperty[ "${i}"  ])`;

Comment: The way you suggested is not correct. Because I still can not use the loop index

Comment: can you share your code in online editors?

Comment: I can not
Because it uses a razor engine.
ViewBag.paramProperty is a list of strings
And I just want to be able to get values viewbag with using (i) as the index of ViewBag.paramProperty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,you need to make sure you `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` with ViewBag.paramProperty,for example:

```
ViewBag.paramProperty = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" });
```

Then try to set a js variable with ViewBag.paramProperty:

```
var paramProperty = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ViewBag.paramProperty));
```

and you can use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < paramProperty.lenght; i++) {
        select: paramProperty[i];
        var element = document.querySelectorAll(`[value="${select}"]`);
        element[0].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code, you are trying to use a server-side variable in client-side.
You can try to declare a javascript variable "paramProperty" and set its value to the ViewBag.paramProperty and then iterate over it